# OpenCV - Adaptive-thresholding / effective noise reduction?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, threshold

I am new to OpenCV and I just read about `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` and decided to try it out.
Sadly there is this huge amount of noise I cannot seem to get rid of.

What are some effective ways to reduce noise so I can draw proper contours? What is the best practice and why?

Here is the snippet:

```js
import cv2
import numpy as np

#####################################
winWidth = 640
winHeight = 840
brightness = 100

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, winWidth)
cap.set(4, winHeight)
cap.set(10, brightness)

kernel = (5, 5)

###########################################

def preprocessing(frame):
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # mask = cv2.inRange(imgHsv, lower, upper)
    imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, kernel, 1)
    gaussC = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
    imgDial = cv2.dilate(gaussC, kernel, iterations=3)
    imgErode = cv2.erode(imgDial, kernel, iterations=1)

    return imgDial


def getcontours(imPrePro):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imPrePro, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        cv2.drawContours(imgCon, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)





###################################################

while (cap.isOpened()):
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success == True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        imgCon = frame.copy()
        imPrePro = preprocessing(frame)
        getcontours(imPrePro)
        cv2.imshow("Preprocessed", imPrePro)
        cv2.imshow("Original", imgCon)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is best if we look at the `blockSize` and `C` parameters.

Form the [source](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3):

> blockSize: Size of a pixel neighborhood that is used to calculate a threshold value for the pixel: 3, 5, 7, and so on.

> C:    Constant subtracted from the mean or weighted mean (see the details below). Normally, it is positive but may be zero or negative as well.

In your example you set `C` to 2:

```py
gaussC = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
```

| C=2 | C=8 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

As you can see, you need to play with `blockSize` and `C` parameters to get the desired result from adaptive-threshold.

In this question, we achieve less-noise by increasing `C` parameter.

Comment: This looks great but wont i have to change these parameters evetime i would go into a new setting since C is basically "brightness"? Or did I understand this wrong?

Comment: Then you need a deep-learning based method. Unfortunately, there is no global parameters fits to every-situation in adaptive-threshold.

Comment: Hmm okey, I might do that later on. For now ill try fixed parameters then. What are the max Values of those parameters so I can translate them to a slider.

Comment: Because `adaptive-threhsold` is an image-processing method with user given parameters. You want  parameters learned from the current situation. That's only possible with deep-learning method.

Comment: What if I would try to do background subtraction for now and try to pair it with adaptive thresholding?

Comment: Sound reasonable, why don't give a try?